# reusable component with react-native linear gradient

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a reusable component with linear gradient which can be used to dynamically change each page's theme/color but i keep getting an error `cannot read property of children undefined`.

```
import React from 'react';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';




export const GradientStyle = ({ theme }) => {

const { primary, primaryGradient2, primaryGradient1 } = theme;
    return (
        <LinearGradient
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        colors={[primary, primaryGradient2, primaryGradient1]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </LinearGradient>
    );
};
```

usage

```
import {GradientStyle} from '../../../styles/theme/GradientTheme'

const theme1 ={
    primary: '#4c669f',
    primaryGradient2: '#3b5998',
    primaryGradient1: '#192f6a'
}

    render() {
        return (

             <GradientStyle colors={theme1}>
                               .......content
            </GradientStyle>


        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `this.props` in a functional component. You have to do add it to the destructuring parameter, like this:

```
export const GradientStyle = ({ children, theme }) => {
    const { primary, primaryGradient2, primaryGradient1 } = theme;
    return (
        <LinearGradient
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        colors={[primary, primaryGradient2, primaryGradient1]}>
        {children}
      </LinearGradient>
    );
};
```

You can then create a `GradientStyle` like this:

```
import {GradientStyle} from '../../../styles/theme/GradientTheme'

const theme1 ={
    primary: '#4c669f',
    primaryGradient2: '#3b5998',
    primaryGradient1: '#192f6a'
};

render() {
    return (
        <GradientStyle theme={theme1}></GradientStyle>
    );
}
```

Comment: i get back cannot not read 'primary', does primary need to be a variable

Comment: `primary`, `primaryGradient2`, and `primaryGradient1`, have to be properties of the `theme` variable.

Comment: Your prop is called `theme` inside the `GradientStyle` component. But you call it `colors` when you call the component. You have to give this the same name. Check my answer for an update.